# Convertir table html a dataTables

Tags: php, html, mysql, datatables

poseo un tabla **html** la cual genero con php y mysql, la idea es convertirla a **dataTables**, el código que poseo:

```
  <table  id="dataTablePreguntas " class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Pregunta</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
          <th>Categoria</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          $data = $db->query(" SELECT 
            p.id, p.nombre, p.peso, c.nombre AS categoria, 
            c.peso AS pesoCategoria, p.estado
            FROM preguntas p
            LEFT JOIN categorias c ON p.categoria_id = c.id
            WHERE p.estado=1 ORDER BY c.nombre "
          )->fetchAll();
          $contador = 0;
          $totalData = count($data);
          if($totalData > 0){
            foreach ($data as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><?=$contador+=1; ?></td>
          <td class="text-left"><?=$row['nombre']?></td>
          <td class="text-center"><?=$row['peso']?></td>
          <td class="text-left"><b><?=$row['categoria']?></b></td>
          <td class="text-center"><?=$row['pesoCategoria']?></td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php 
            if($row['estado']==1){
              echo "<p style='color:green'><b>Activo</b></p>";
            }else{
              echo "<p style='color:red'>Inactivo</b></p>";
            }
            ?>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='editarCategoria("<?=$row["id"]?>");'>Editar</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        }
        }else{
          echo "<tr><td colspan='7'>Sin preguntas que listar</td></tr>";
        }

        ?>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Pregunta</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
          <th>Categoria</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Para convertirla he tratado:

```
$('#dataTablePreguntas').find("table").DataTable();
```

o con:

```
$('#dataTablePreguntas').DataTable();
```

tengo incluido las librerias asi:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <title>Administrar Evaluacion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 ....
....
```

quizá alguna sugerencias gracias de antemano..!!

Comment: Al momento de asignar el id en la etiqueta table estás dejando un espacio al final, y cuando lo capturas en jQuery no tienes en cuenta ese espacio... no se si fue error tuyo redactando la pregunta o si tienes tu código así, revisa eso!

Comment: @BenderPaisa fue algon tan simple :( gracias me sirvio y funciono !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error era que estas asignando un espacio en blanco al valor del atributo id de tu tabla.

Aunque tu pregunta se puede tomar como un error tipográfico y podría terminar cerrada decidí responderla para ampliar un poco la información acerca del atributo id:

Como se explica en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id), **El valor de este atributo no debe contener espacios en blanco** por la simple razón de que `id` recibe un solo valor además de que debe ser único en todo el documento, caso contrario al atributo `class` cuyos valores deben ir separados por espacios.

EN el siguiente ejemplo podrás observar la funcionalidad de ambos selectores y ambos casos:

```js
console.log($("#divID").html());
console.log($(".divClass").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divID ">DIV ID</div>

<div class="divClass ">DIV CLASS</div>
```

Comment: Genial excelente explicación gracias..!!